# What rhetorical device is "she wears mink all day and fox all night" using?

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech, puns

What rhetorical device is the following statement using?

> She wears mink all day and fox all night.

It's not a pun, it's not a syllepsis. Is there a word for false-puns of this sort?

Answer (score 5):

Yes but it is a pun and a rather saucy one too.

> The pun, also called paronomasia, is a form of word play which suggests two or more meanings...

I think it would be classified as a homophonic [pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun).

Comment: It utterly fails at the homophony for me. So much so that instead of a "thwack", my initial reaction to it was "huh?"